# Windows XP Home SP2 won't start loading software updates

Tags: windows-xp

I recently re-installed non-English Windows XP Home SP2 to two computers. Why the computers don't start downloading software updates ? I have valid licenses and the copies have been activated successfully.

Over the years I have made several XP installations from the same media and there has been no issues earlier (i.e. the software updates have started a quite soon).

I do have the automatic software updates turned on (as I have always).

Comment: Download the SP3 by hand.  I seem to remember that updates are not provided to Windows XP SP2 machines.

Comment: Agree with Ramhound - see http://www.infoworld.com/t/windows/windows-xp-sp2-updates-end-july-13-dont-panic-050

Comment: @DaveM: I've tried nothing after SP2 install because the automatic software update was expected to take care of the rest. There is no error messages I'm aware of.

Comment: @Ramhound: Are you referring to [Windows XP Service Pack 3 Network Installation Package for IT Professionals and Developers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24) or to something else ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I got it. Browsing from [What does it mean if my version of Windows is no longer supported?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/what-does-end-of-support-mean) ends to the download page on my previous comment. But it confuses me that Automatic Update is still recommended way even it doesn't work anymore with SP2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [What does it mean if my version of Windows is no longer supported?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/what-does-end-of-support-mean):

> Support for Windows XP SP2 ended on July 13, 2010. To continue support, make sure you've installed Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3). For more information, see [Learn how to install Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/learn-how-to-install-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3).

From [Learn how to install Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/learn-how-to-install-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3):

> In order to install SP3, you must first have Windows XP Service Pack 1a (SP1a) or Service Pack 2 (SP2) installed. These are also available when you have Automatic Updates turned on. For more information about these and other Windows service packs, go to the [Service Pack Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/service-packs).

Note that *"These are also available when you have Automatic Updates turned on."* is not true, because SP2 support has ended.

From [Service Pack Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/service-packs) Windows XP:

> [Download SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24) from the Download Center (advanced)

There one gets the SP3 that can be installed on top of SP2.

The download suggested also some other packages that I also downloaded and installed.

Now I do have SP3 re-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install the latest [Windows Update Agent 3.0 on this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932139.aspx), select the x86 version. Automatic updates will work now.

Or [just click here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=100334) for the XP 32bit version direct download, and install it, then windows updates will work.

Comment: Sorry, but I understand nothing from the linked page. The context and terms are unfamiliar for me.

Comment: You don't know how to click on a link to download a file?